# how to get html code of an element on a webpage

Tags: java, android, html, webview

Im creating a simple web scraping app.

I already learned on how to extract the html code from `webview` to `textview` on android.
Right now I dont want to display the whole html code, I just need a specific element to be display on `textview`.

My question in case you didnt understand my problem.

I want to learn on how can I get the specific element of a webpage

If you have an idea on how to solve the logic of this problem, please comment down below,
If you can give a code Im very very thankful to you

Comment: If you want to scrape the web then do not use a webview to do do. Use a http/https component. If you parsed something from the source then use a webview to display that part.

Comment: Use JSOUP for parsing html source.